# Drag and drop a single entity of ImageView and EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-imageview

I am trying to create an android app for having formations like this one with drag and drop functionality. My challenge is to combine a image view and edit text as a single entity so that they can dragged around and be placed in the appropriate position. How do i approach this? I have tried the following:

1. Edit text with background image or drawables to the top. The problem is the size of the drawable cannot be altered
2. Separate imageview and edit text in relative layout. When I drag, only the edit text moves. Not the image.

[image]

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: You can create a custom view, which will hold your ImageView and EditText. Then apply drag and drop feature to your custom view.

Comment: @MohitCharadva It doesn't even have to be custom. Just a LinearLayout will do.